# How to modify System Keyspace (and its columnfamilies) in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-2.1

I am wondering if there is a workaround to `ALTER` the columnfamilies of System keyspace such as:
`schema_columns` and `schema_columnfamilies`

I tried to type ALTER CQL in CQLSH and it returned

> Unauthorized: Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="system keyspace is not user-modifiable."

Is there a root-like account in cassandra that can help me modify System keyspace?

Comment: what do you want to change?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Hi, I would like to ALTER the `schema_columns` table to change the GC_GRACE_SECONDS to investigate a sstable issue

Comment: But is it an issue with an SSTable from `schema_columns`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modification to system keyspaces is not allowed.

If using cassandra 3.x then try creating Materialized view on system keyspace tables for your requirement.